# How to make 2 elements floated side by side, to line up with the banner at the top?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm building a simple website layout. I have a banner at the top, and a div boxe and an image underneath it, both floated to the left. I want to get the image of the woman inline with the right side of the header banner. I've tried using margin, but it either makes it go off the page, or it doesn't quite line up.

Here's the CSS:

```
.topbanner {
width:100%;
background-color:black;
padding:1%;
margin-top:1%;
}

#nav {
text-align:center;

}

.leftcolumn {
width:40%;
height:230px;
background-color: grey;
border: solid red 3px;
margin-top:2%;
float:left;

}

.leftcolumn p {
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:13%;
font-style:italic;
font-size:20px;
}

.woman {
width:55%;
height:230px;
border: solid black 3px;
margin-top:2%;
float:left;
margin-left:4%;
```

Here's a link to the codepen: 
http://codepen.io/Pea92/pen/JdpoqN

Answer (score 0):

Just float the right column right

```
.rightcolumn {

width:55%;
height:230px;
border: solid black 3px;
margin-top:2%;
float:right;
margin-left:4%;
}
```

here add this (take the width out)

```
.topbanner {

  background-color:black;
  padding:1%;
  margin-top:1%;
}
```

[view my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLawnwr3/)

Comment: Hey thanks, but this didn't work. The image still isn't lined up with the right side of the top black banner.

Comment: ok I updated, you didn't have an image before, the new change will fix it. I attached a fiddle

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I wonder why the width of 100% would be making it do that, strange. Thanks!

Comment: I've also been trying to get the .line div to separate from the content above it for ages. For some reason 'margin-top' isn't working. Dyou think it's because of the floating? I've cleared the float on it :S
http://codepen.io/Pea92/pen/JdpoqN

Comment: no, you can use floats and margins together. You just cannot use vertical align with floats

Comment: Look at it now, is this what you want that line to do https://jsfiddle.net/pLawnwr3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here, I edited the CSS for you.

```
.woman {
  width: 55%;
  height: 230px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
```

You just need to float .woman (image) right and perhaps decrease the margin-left to 3%.

It seems like the width of the left column and the image should have added up to 99%, but it might have exceeded 100% due to the 3px borders given to the left column and image.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not really lined up! Grrrr. I even reduced the borders